# How can I get Value "Observer" object's Value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue.js.
this.suspendedReserveMemo has the following data.

```
this.suspendedReserveMemo [__ob__: Observer]650: "memo3"651: "memo4"652: ""653: ""654: ""655: ""656: ""657: ""658: ""659: ""660:""661: ""662: ""length: 663__ob__: Observer {value: Array(663),dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}[[Prototype]]: Array
```

[image]

I think I can get “memo3” with this.suspendedReserveMemo[650] but it’s undefined,

How can I get “memo3”?

```
getSuspendReserveMemo () {
  const roomMemoArray = []
  this.schedule.map(value => {
    axios
      .get(`/shop/${this.selectedShopId}/room/${value.roomId}/suspend_memo`)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 204) {
          roomMemoArray[value.roomId] = ''
        } else {
          roomMemoArray[value.roomId] = res.data
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        roomMemoArray[value.roomId] = ''
      })
  })
  this.suspendedReserveMemo = roomMemoArray
  console.log('this.suspendedReserveMemo', this.suspendedReserveMemo)
  console.log('this.suspendedReserveMemo[650]', this.suspendedReserveMemo[650])
},
```

Comment: [DO NOT use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of axios requests, the `console.log` might be executed before the requests are completed, resulting in undefined values.

Comment: which version of vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous nature of axios requests, the `console.log` might be executed before the requests are completed, resulting in undefined values.

You can use `Promise.all` to wait for all the axios requests to complete before setting the `this.suspendedReserveMemo` property and logging the values.

```
getSuspendReserveMemo() {
  const roomMemoArray = [];

  const axiosPromises = this.schedule.map(value => {
    return axios.get(`/shop/${this.selectedShopId}/room/${value.roomId}/suspend_memo`)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 204) {
          roomMemoArray[value.roomId] = '';
        } else {
          roomMemoArray[value.roomId] = res.data;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        roomMemoArray[value.roomId] = '';
      });
  });

  Promise.all(axiosPromises)
    .then(() => {
      this.suspendedReserveMemo = roomMemoArray;
      console.log('this.suspendedReserveMemo', this.suspendedReserveMemo);
      console.log('this.suspendedReserveMemo[650]', this.suspendedReserveMemo[650]);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
},
```

Comment: Yes this one works!